# Laptop is booting straight into Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, uefi

I had a pre-installed Windows 10 in my Laptop. I had decided to install Ubuntu 18.04 by creating a partition in the single hard disk. Everything worked like a charm for two months without any problem. I had the boot menu that would allow me to select between Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

Last week on a fine day, after I shut down my computer and switched it back on, selecting Ubuntu showed grub failure screen. It was not loading Ubuntu at all. Then I decided to use boot-repair which automatically did some recommended repairs. Now, the issue is that the boot menu is no longer available and the system boots directly into Windows 10.

I am not sure if this is relevant but many solution involved UEFI mode for BIOS, but I have come to know that upon typing msinfo32 in Run Command in Windows 10, it shows the BIOS mode as "Legacy".

I made a bootable Ubuntu USB and entered Ubuntu using "Try Ubuntu". The hard disk portion where I installed Ubuntu i.e. /dev/sda6 is still available. I am not sure if it's corrupt.

I tried implementing "bcdedit" as well but still it's going directly into Windows 10.

I was hoping if someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: try update-grub. See if that works.

Comment: Do I have to go in via "Try Ubuntu" using bootable USB?

Comment: yeah sorry to mention that!

Comment: I also noticed that the filesystem for the partition containing "Linux" is showing as RAW when using Ext2 Volume Manager tool. Isn't it supposed to be "ext2"? Did it get corrupted? I don't know if Windows updated during my last shut down.

Comment: It should be ext4, but some Windows third party tools may not see it correctly. Windows does not recognize Linux formats at all. RAW is unformatted in Windows. You should use Ubuntu live installer to review partitions or make Linux repairs. Use Linux tools for Linux and Windows tools for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Set your BIOS back to UEFI booting, for Windows 10.

Make sure Windows still boots.

See Rod Smith's answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/1072783), and use the bcdedit method to fix your problem.

Comment: bcdedit did not work. How do we set the BIOS back to UEFI mode? I can't find it in my BIOS. It's in the Legacy mode.